# HttpUrlConnection 403-forbidden error Android

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

Below is my code snippet. 403 error coming. COuld anyone please give the solution to overcome this 403 error. This is the post JSON request.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
            trustAllHosts();
            URL url = new URL(postUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            String userCredentials = username+":"+password;
            String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(android.util.Base64.encode(userCredentials.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("X-CSRF-TOKEN",token);
            conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:221.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0");


            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            PostRootObject postRootObject = new PostRootObject();



            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            String json = gson.toJson(postRootObject);

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

            Log.e("Json object",""+jsonObject);

            DataOutputStream os = new 
            DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

//                os.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(jsonObject.toString(), "UTF-8"));
            os.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());

            os.flush();


            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();


            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response+=line;
                }
            }
            else {
                response="";

            }

            Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
            Log.i("MSG" , conn.getResponseMessage());
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried POSTing using postman ? Maybe your auth method is expecting bit different input

Comment: tried, working fine with postman. Problem only with code :(

Comment: httpurlconnection.getErrorStream() throwing "buffer(com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource@91b93f2).inputStream()" this error.

Comment: Rafael - sorry i have removed original url while posting and replaced it with url. Now updated the post. It is not the url error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing this line from your manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Sorry, I saw 1 min later, that you have solution.

Comment: I have given internet permission also. Moreover i dnt have solution. Waiting for someone to give the solution